# Is it possible to upload two different Childs to an existing child at the same time in Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I want the User to add Friends. When he clicks on the button addFriend two new Childs should be created and uploaded to the Database. The child the new information shall be upload to is called "befreundet" (being friends). 
The JSON tree which should be created should like like this:

```
befreundet
   loggedinUser.uid
         otherUser.uid
                 otherUser.username: " " 
                 otherUser.ProfilePic: " "
   otherUser.uid
         loggedinUser.uid
                 loggedinUser.username: " " 
                 loggedinUser.ProfilePic: " "
```

Here is the code:

```
 @IBAction func addFriend(_ sender: Any) {

    if self.befreunden.titleLabel?.text == "Als Freund hinzufügen" {


        let friendRef = "befreundet/\(self.loggedInUSer!.uid)/\(self.otherUseruid!)"
        let FreundeRef = "befreundet/\(self.otherUseruid!)/\(self.loggedInUSer!.uid)"

        let FriendData = ["username":self.loggedinUSerData?["username"] as! String,
                          "ProfilePic":self.loggedinUSerData?["urltoImage"] as! String]
        let BefreundenData = ["username":self.otherUser?["username"] as? String,
                              "ProfilePic":self.otherUser?["urltoImage"] as? String]

        let childUpdats = [friendRef:BefreundenData,
                           FreundeRef:FriendData]

        databaseRef.updateChildValues(childUpdats)

        let FreundeAnzahl:Int?
        let FriendCount:Int?

        if self.otherUser?["AnzahlFreunde"] == nil {

            FreundeAnzahl = 1
        }else {

            FreundeAnzahl = self.otherUser?["AnzahlFreunde"] as! Int + 1

        }

        if self.loggedinUSerData?["AnzahlFreunde"] == nil {

            FriendCount = 1
        }else {

            FriendCount = self.loggedinUSerData?["AnzahlFreunde"] as! Int + 1
        }

    databaseRef.child("users").child(self.loggedinUSerData?["uid"] as! String).child("AnzahlFreunde").setValue(FreundeAnzahl)
    databaseRef.child("users").child(self.otherUseruid!).child("AnzahlFreunde").setValue(FriendCount)


    }else {

        databaseRef.child("users").child(self.loggedinUSerData?["uid"] as! String).child("AnzahlFreunde").setValue(self.loggedinUSerData?["ANzahlFreunde"] as! Int - 1)
        databaseRef.child("users").child(self.otherUseruid!).child("AnzahlFreunde").setValue(otherUser?["AnzahlFreunde"] as! Int - 1)

         let friendRef = "befreundet/\(self.loggedinUSerData?["uid"] as! String)/\(self.otherUseruid!)"
        let FreundeRef = "befreundet/\(self.otherUseruid!)/\(self.loggedinUSerData?["uid"] as! String)"
        let childUpdates2 = [friendRef:NSNull()]
        let FreundeUpdate2 = [FreundeRef:NSNull()]
        databaseRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates2)
        databaseRef.updateChildValues(FreundeUpdate2)
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing right now ist that only "FreundeRef" is being uploaded. 
Has anyone any idea why that is?

Comment: Are you using Security Rules? Does the user have access to the other users data in the database?

Comment: The solution is to use a multi-location update. See these blog posts:  https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html and https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html

Comment: I don't know if this was the problem. I do use it now. However the real issue was that, the username amd the profilepic string of the otheruser were nil. I created new variables to save that information in viewdidLoad, so I can use them later on.